# C# construction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, abstract, ienumerator

I try to understand one Unity example script and I found following code in examples:

```
 protected IEnumerator SmoothMovement(Vector3 end) {
    float sqrRemainingDistance = (transform.position - end).sqrMagnitude;

    while (sqrRemainingDistance > float.Epsilon) {
        Vector3 newPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(rb2d.position, end, inverseMoveTime * Time.deltaTime);
        rb2d.MovePosition(newPosition);
        sqrRemainingDistance = (transform.position - end).sqrMagnitude;
        yield return null;
    }
}

public abstract void OnCantMove <T> (T component)
    where T : Component;
```

I really don't understand the two last lines. What do they mean and what are they doing?

Comment: The last two lines define an abstract method, which inheriting classes would need to override.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a generic parameter with a constraint saying that any object passed to this must be of type `Component`

[Constraints on Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Those tow lines define an abstract method returning nothing and expecting any arbitrary `Component`. Any class implementing your abstract one should also implement this abstract method.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a method signature.  The breakdown looks like:

`public abstract`

a public method, that must be overriden in derived classes

`void`

No return value

`OnCantMove`

Method is named `OnCantMove`

`<T>(T component)`

It takes a type parameter `T`, and an instance of type `T` that it is calling `component`.  Often, the compiler is smart enough when you call this method to figure out the type parameter on it's own, if its using an instance parameter of that type.  So potentially, you could call this leaving off the `<T>` parameter.

`where T : Component`

the type parameter `T` is constrained to be of type `Component`